# Need mfgr of double hung casements w/"PG" engraved on lock

Tags: windows

I purchased a mobile home that has had its windows redone since DOM. I would like to have additional windows put in, and would prefer them to match existing. Only problem, I can't find any identifying numbers, letters or anything on the windows except an outline of PG is engraved on the metal bracket/rise of the lock (pic attached). I've googled endlessly and can not figure out who manufactures these windows?

They are double-glazed, double-hung casements, non-tilt, 44.5"x51" @ 4 "panels" across (panels created by vinyl dividers between panes).

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no guarantee the maker of the lock hardware is the maker of the windows.

Comment: Look for a faint etched stamp at one corner of the glass.

Answer (score 2):

That logo looks like [Portland Glass](http://portlandglass.com/), located in lovely Portland Maine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is your location? There are literally hundreds (maybe thousands?) of aluminum window manufacturers. The one that is most likely is [PG Aluminum](http://www.pgaluminium.co.za/aluminium_windows/aluminium_windows.html); a South African manufacturer.

Comment: haha, wow! I'm in Maine, on the coast. Probably NOT the SA mfg. but i will check into it anyway! thank you!

Comment: Yeah, probably not African. Maybe the wonders of technology would allow you to search with that picture of the maker's mark, to find similar images?